# Applying Gradient to button doesn't reflect in swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uibutton

I have written the following code and don't know what I'm doing wrong the button is not reflecting the gradient

I also tried calling my function under awakefromNib

```
class ButtonGradient: UIButton {

    var color1 = #colorLiteral(red: 0.3411764801, green: 0.6235294342, blue: 0.1686274558, alpha: 1)
    var color2 = #colorLiteral(red: 0.521568656, green: 0.1098039225, blue: 0.05098039284, alpha: 1)

    var gradient = CAGradientLayer()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        applyGradient()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        applyGradient()

    }


    func applyGradient() {

        gradient.frame = self.bounds
        gradient.colors = [color1,color2]
        gradient.startPoint = CGPoint.zero
        gradient.endPoint = CGPoint.init(x: 0.0, y: 0.5)
        gradient.locations = [0,1]
        self.layer.addSublayer(gradient)


    }
}
```

I want to apply gradient vertically to my button.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple, here you are

```
    @IBDesignable class GradientButton: UIButton {

    @IBInspectable var topColor: UIColor = .white
    @IBInspectable var bottomColor: UIColor = .black

    override class var layerClass: AnyClass {
        return CAGradientLayer.self
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        (layer as? CAGradientLayer)?.colors = [topColor.cgColor, bottomColor.cgColor]
    }

}
```

Just change class from UIButton to GradientButton

Comment: I used this in a custom class 
   
    func applyGradient(colors : [Any]) {
        
        gradient.frame = self.bounds
        gradient.colors = colors
        gradient.startPoint = CGPoint.zero
        gradient.endPoint = CGPoint.init(x: 0.0, y: 0.9)
        gradient.locations = [0,1]
        self.layer.addSublayer(gradient)
        self.layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.height / 2
        self.clipsToBounds = true
    }